# Rearranging Email Folders in Evolution

Tags: gnome, email, evolution

In the Evolution email client, all of my folders in my email account are organized alphabetically by default. The same goes for my search folders. Is there a way to rearrange the folders? There's a specific order in which I like to keep them.

Thanks in advance to the community for their help!

Answer (score 3):

Email accounts can be organized by navigating to *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Mail Accounts*. From this view the email accounts can be dragged and dropped to reorder them.

I have managed to sort folders before, but I don’t remember how and I’m unable to find an option to do so at this point.

**Edit**

Folders can be edited by adding a `Sort` property to `~/.config/evolution/mail/folder-tweaks.ini`.

For example:

```ini
[folder://0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567/INBOX]
Sort=1

[folder://0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567/GitHub]
Sort=2

[folder://0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567/GitLab]
Sort=3
```

The order of sections doesn’t matter, but they can be rearranged to match your sorting order.

Comment: Folders can be sorted in the GUI, via `Menu > Folder > Edit Sort Order...`, as mentioned in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1742935/1228203), and doing so would create `folder-tweaks.ini`